# Can I control / avoid the rubber space at a given position?

Tags: spacing

This is a quite general question. Examples include if I want to be certain about the v. space between two specified paragraphs but am ok to leave the rest for LaTeX algorithm to increase or decrease the spaces as it considers appropriate.

This applies to horizontal direction (in a line) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can go

```
ZZZZZ   

\vspace{-\parskip}
\vspace{3cm}

ZZZZZ
```

and have a non stretchy fixed space of 3cm instead of the value of `\parskip` at that point.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean it's to `\parskip' that the rubber padding is associated?